# Maven Build Issue with spring-boot-starter-parent <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, maven-plugin, spring-boot-maven-plugin

```
I have tried multiple options changing the spring boot starter parent versions updating the 
        repository URL in the POM file, But still no luck keep on getting the below issue.
```

Tried adding the repository config in the pom still getting the issue. I have tried deletng the entire m2 repo but no luck its trying to download other tuff but not the plugin.
Error :

```
    plugin org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.1.3.RELEASE or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:jar:2.1.3.RELEASE: Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:pom:2.1.3.RELEASE from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Failed to transfer http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-maven-plugin/2.1.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-maven-plugin-2.1.3.RELEASE.pom. Error code 501, HTTPS Required
```

Comment: Can you post the relevant part of your `pom.xml`?

Comment: The transfer must use https instead of http...you are using a very old Maven version upgrade to most recent version of Maven... as the error message says: `Error code 501, HTTPS Required `...

Comment: Below is  the pom.xml which i have in my project.
<repository>
   <id>central</id>
   <name>Central Repository</name>
   <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
   <layout>default</layout>
   <snapshots>
    <enabled>false</enabled>
   </snapshots>
  </repository>
Its https only,Still facing same issue.

Answer (score 0):

The url from where your code is trying to fetch the dependency should be an https url

[expected url](https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-maven-plugin/2.1.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-maven-plugin-2.1.3.RELEASE.pom)

in your case it is :-

[your code URL](http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-maven-plugin/2.1.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-maven-plugin-2.1.3.RELEASE.pom)

You might need to change your artifactory url

Comment: could you please help me where i need to update this url.